# SQL Query with return a value when no records found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having problem with a query. If someone could help me of how to return a value of 0 when no records found.
Here's my SQL Statement. I tried to use the coalesce and max with this statement, received an error of

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Status) as Count,
       Status,
       [Area Name]
FROM  dbo.aspx_Inspection 
where [Area Name] like '%Frozen%'
  and (Status='Failed')
  AND DATEDIFF(day,[Assigned Date],GETDATE()) between 0 and 360
GROUP BY Status,
         [Area Name]
ORDER BY Status desc
```

Result

```
|(No column name)|  Status  |Area Name|
|----------------|----------|-----------|
|26               | Failed   |Frozen Pond Arena|
```

Comment: So, you're going to need values for Status & [Area Name] along with the zero. Should those be null?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some sample data and the desired result (as text).

Comment: @Ben Yes, I need to show this to a pie chart. - The status is the label for Y-axis and the count value is for x-axis. So I need them in the query statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a master list of status in a table like Master.Status, you could do this

```
SELECT ISNULL(T.Count,0), M.Status, T.AreaName
FROM
Master.Status M 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(Status) as Count,
       Status,
       [Area Name]
FROM  dbo.aspx_Inspection 
where [Area Name] like '%Frozen%'
  and (Status='Failed')
  AND DATEDIFF(day,[Assigned Date],GETDATE()) between 0 and 360
GROUP BY Status,
         [Area Name]
)T
ON T.Status=M.Status
ORDER BY M.Status desc
```

In case Master.Status does not exists, and you are sure that all status codes are in dbo.aspx_Inspection you could also do

```
SELECT ISNULL(T.Count,0), M.Status, T.AreaName
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM  dbo.aspx_Inspection ) M 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(Status) as Count,
       Status,
       [Area Name]
FROM  dbo.aspx_Inspection 
where [Area Name] like '%Frozen%'
  and (Status='Failed')
  AND DATEDIFF(day,[Assigned Date],GETDATE()) between 0 and 360
GROUP BY Status,
         [Area Name]
)T
ON T.Status=M.Status
ORDER BY M.Status desc
```

Comment: Perhaps something like this but UNION, rather than JOIN, the two result sets together so everything comes back in just three columns?

Comment: The second statement works. I just added  a where statement at the end like T 
ON T.Status=M.Status
where m.Status = 'Failed'
ORDER BY M.Status desc